# Iteration problem with pairs of coordinates, python

Tags: python, google-api, iteration, coordinates

I'm having a hard time figuring out, why I can't -

1) Iterate over the set of coordinates that's created from coords,

2) Finding the streets overall when the link pops up (usually with sets of 20 listings)

3) Find the exact vicinities that have only "road" written.

Please help.

My end goal is to yield a set of coordinates that provide me vicinities in a radius of `9000`, and within those vicinities, I can find `"road"` and other keywords.

```
import requests
import json

APIKEY = "akakak"

import geopandas as gpd
pagetoken = akakakakakak
pagetoken = None
fp = "/Users/akakak/Documents/akakak/akakaka.shp"
data = gpd.read_file(fp)
enugu = data.loc[data['ADM1FIPSNA'] == 'Enugu']
coords=[]

for long, lat in zip(enugu.geometry.y, enugu.geometry.x):
    coords.append((long,lat))


def findPlaces(loc = ('x','y'), radius=9000, pagetoken = None):
    loc = coords.append((long,lat))
    type = "school"
    xtype = "vicinity"
    xxtype = "road"
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={lat},{long}&radius={radius}&type={type}&key={APIKEY}{pagetoken}".format(lat = lat, long = long, radius = radius, type = type,APIKEY = APIKEY, pagetoken = "&pagetoken="+pagetoken if pagetoken else "")
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    res = json.loads(response.text)
    print(res)
    print("here results ---->>> ", len(res["results"]))
    for result in res["results"]:
        if xxtype in res["results"]:
            if xtype in result["vicinity"]:
                info = ";".join(map(str,[result["name"],result["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],result["geometry"]["location"]["lng"],result["types"]]))
                print(info)
    '
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and so untestable, but I notice that in the first line of your findPlaces() func, you're setting loc to coords.append(...).  The list append() method returns None. Do you want to be pulling a loc out of coords there rather than appending one and getting loc equal to None?

Comment: I was trying to get the loc out of coords earlier, that wasn't resulting in anything either. What should I try instead @Gary02127

Comment: Again, because your code is incomplete and not runnable, I can only guess. But once you have an array, you can access elements of the array using indeces. I'll take a stab at it below...

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is incomplete and not runnable, I can only guess what you want to do. But once you have an array/list, you can access elements of the list using indexes or by iterating through the list.

In your def findPlaces() func, change the first few lines, like so:

```
def findPlaces(loc, radius=9000, pagetoken = None):
    # loc = coords.append((long,lat))
    loc = long, lat
    type = 'school'
       :
```

And after the func, try iterating through coords, with something like:

```
for loc in coords:
    findPlaces(loc)
```

Hopefully this will help you make some progress. Beyond this, you would really need to post more complete code, along with data files. Ideally you would post something that we can run and see what happens. Stubbing data is a common practice when asking for help.

Comment: How do you attach data files and what is stubbing data? Ill try this and update you.

Comment: "Stubbing" is making mini substitutes so that things will run... So if you need a func to read from a file, you might "stub" it by returning a string and pretending that it came from a file...  I'm not sure how to attach a file to this site, but you can always extend your code to include more strings, some of which include required data that might otherwise have come from a file.